# Symbol with tilde AND sub/super-scripts

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, tilde

I need to typeset a mathematical symbol consisting of a letter with a tilde and both sub- and super-scripts. The subscript is fine, but the tilde runs into the superscript. How can I fix this?

Here is the culprit:

```
\tilde{t}_{k_1}^{k_3}
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little space can be added at the start of the superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \tilde{t}_{k_1}^{\,k_3} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]